# Forcing mutual exclusion for multi branch pipeline builds

Tags: jenkins, groovy

The following is an excerpt from a Jenkinsfile used in a multi-branch pipeline:

```
def GetNextFreePort() {
    lock ('portProvider') {
        def port = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '((Get-NetTCPConnection | Sort-Object -Property LocalPort | Select-Object -Last 1).LocalPort) + 1')
    }

    return port.trim()
}
```

I'd like the line that gets the port number (on windows) to return a different port for each branch. However, despite using the lockable resources plugin, I cannot serialize access to the powershell callout that gets the next available port.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to achieve what I wanted to do via the Jenkins lock resource plugin. Here is my method to obtain an external port number and start the container:

```
  def StartContainer() {
        PORT_NUMBER = GetNextFreePort()
        bat "docker run -e \"ACCEPT_EULA=Y\" -e \"SA_PASSWORD=P@ssword1\" --name ${CONTAINER_NAME} -d -i -p ${PORT_NUMBER}:1433 microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-GA"    
        powershell "While (\$((docker logs ${CONTAINER_NAME} | select-string ready | select-string client).Length) -eq 0) { Start-Sleep -s 1 }"    
    }
```

and here is the call to this which is wrapped by a call to lock:

```
 stage('start container') {
            steps {
                RemoveContainer()
                timeout(time: 20, unit: 'SECONDS') {
                    lock ('create SQL Server container') {
                        StartContainer()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```